# Scala reduceLeft: 0.asInstanceOf[B]

Tags: scala, null, scala-collections

Continuing [my series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44288838/5091346) about strange source code.

Looking at Scala 2.12.12 `scala.collection.TraversableOnce#reduceLeft#reducer` I've found a very strange line:

```scala
def reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, A) => B): B = {
  if (isEmpty)
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty.reduceLeft")

  object reducer extends Function1[A, Unit] {
    var first = true
    var acc: B = 0.asInstanceOf[B] // <<<<===

    override def apply(x: A): Unit =
      if (first) {
        acc = x
        first = false
      }
      else acc = op(acc, x)
  }
  self foreach reducer
  reducer.acc
}
```

What actually `0.asInstanceOf[B]` does? Is it a workaround for making each type "nullable"?

For example, having

```
Seq("1", "2").reduceLeft(_ + _)
```

means the following code in the runtime

```
var acc: B = 0.asInstanceOf[String]
```

Why this cannot be simply replaced with `var acc: B = null`? Because it would require to introduce `implicit ev: Null <:< A1` or what?

**Update:**

Moreover, simply casting `Int` to any other type throws an exception:

```
println(0.asInstanceOf[String])
```

Throws a runtime exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

But why it doesn't throw an exception in case with reducer?

**Update 2:**

Diving deeper,

```
def foo[A]: A = 1.asInstanceOf[A]

println(foo[String])                 // 1
println(foo[LocalDateTime])          // 1
println(foo[LocalDateTime].getClass) // java.lang.Integer
```

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/aaabramov/be9eb28c9f7a8c4bb2c4c6064defeb39)

Comment: Yes it seems to be a way to trick the compiler to have an empty value.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yep. But behavior is so strange... I've added several more examples to the question to demonstrate how ridiculous it behaves :D

Comment: The bad cast is a bit like a tree, falling in the forest: it only throws when you _look_ at it.

Comment: `var acc: B = null`  wouldn't work if `B` is a primitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

You indeed cannot assign `null` to a value of type `B` that is not specified as `B <: AnyRef` without a cast. However, Scala generics are erased at runtime. The post-erasure post-boxing code would look something like that:

```
def reduceLeft(op: Function2): Object = {
  if (isEmpty)
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty.reduceLeft")

  object reducer extends Function1 {
    var first = true
    var acc: Object = BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(0)

    override def apply(x: Object): Unit =
      if (first) {
        acc = x
        first = false
      }
      else acc = op(acc, x)
  }
  self foreach reducer
  reducer.acc
}
```

Notice that the cast is gone too. There's zero information about what `B` was so there's no check to make.

Unlike there:

```
println(0.asInstanceOf[String])
```

This cast won't be erased, as String is a known type.

The erasure also explains why the `foo` calls work, as foo's erasure is basically:

```
def foo: Object = BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(1)
```

Recall that `println` is defined as `def println(any: Any): Unit`, and post-scalac `Any` is replaced by `Object`. Therefore, when you're doing

```
println(foo[String])                 // 1
println(foo[LocalDateTime])          // 1
```

the resulting `1` is never assigned to anything that would do a runtime class check. The object you get out is passed directly to `println`.

But this will cause a ClassCastException since the result of `foo` needs to be cast down to `String` for `printString` call

```
def printString(s: String) = println(s)
printString(foo[String])
```

and this will also fail at runtime:

```
val str = foo[String]
```

because Scala will infer the type of `str` to be `String`, and then runtime will fail to cast to that type.

---

Now, the part of an answer I *don't* have is why they didn't do `var acc: B = _` (which only works inside classes/objects) or `var acc: B = null.asInstanceOf[B]` (which works everywhere you can define a `var`). It could probably just be a line that survived through a bunch of refactors.

Comment: I like that `Learning Scala when daily brainpower isn't all used up.` in your profile 

Answer (score 2):

In Scala 2.13 `0.asInstanceOf[B]` was changed to `null.asInstanceOf[B]` by [Expression for all zero bits #8767](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8767)

> `null.asInstanceOf[A]` is more kosher than 0.
>
> It doesn't matter here because the value is never used and is always
> re-assigned.
>
> It's too bad someone started accusing `var x: A = _` of undue ugliness.
> That remains the best expression of non-assignment.

In [Scala 3](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/wildcard-init.html) we could write

```
trait Foo[B]:                                                                                                                                        
  var acc: B = compiletime.uninitialized
```

which IMO conveys intention clearly.

---

Related [What is happening with 0.asInstanceOf[B] in Scala reduceLeft implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465356/what-is-happening-with-0-asinstanceofb-in-scala-reduceleft-implementation)

Comment: Oh man, this has been already answered! I wasn't able to find it. Will close this as a duplicate. And thanks for pointing out to the PR.